# Are there examples where mathematicians needs to calculate big combinations

Tags: probability, combinatorics

With the $C_n^k$ formula, I managed to optimize it for finding very big numbers such as
$C_{7130}^{7125}$ rather quickly. I could have used GMP or Ruby because unsigned long don't hold a lot of values, but here is my question:

Are there applications where people need to compute such numbers ? Because the plain factorial methods can be quite long compared to my method...

Comment: Have you already checked your formula/algorithm against those provided by most mathematical programming packages? (Matlab, Mathematica, R, etc...)

Comment: Or this one: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastBinomialFunction.html (based on http://www.jstor.org/pss/2323099)?

Comment: ...or this one, which is similar: http://www.numbertheory.org/php/binomial.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are all sorts of reasons why you might want to know a large binomial coefficient. Is this what you have?

```
some_int_type nCr = 1 ;
if (r > n/2) r = n - r ;
for (int i = 1 ; i <= r ; i++, n--)
  nCr *= n, nCr /= i ;
```

Comment: yes, except the characters aren't in that exact order.

Comment: WELL THEY SHOULD BE!